# Valgrind Invalid read of size 1

Tags: c++, debugging, valgrind

I've been scratching my hair out but can't seem to find what is wrong with the following code. Here is the small snippet of valgrind output that it generates

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --track-origins=yes ./main
==9968== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==9968== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==9968== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==9968== Command: ./main
==9968== 
==9968== Invalid read of size 1
==9968==    at 0x404B77: operator*(float, Color const&) (Color.h:30)
==9968==    by 0x403532: Image<Color>::bilinearScale(unsigned short, unsigned short) const (Image.h:533)
==9968==    by 0x404109: main (main.cpp:86)
==9968==  Address 0x5dce722 is 2 bytes after a block of size 14,400 alloc'd
==9968==    at 0x4C2AFE7: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9968==    by 0x404CD7: Image<Color>::Image(unsigned short const&, unsigned short const&) (Image.h:173)
==9968==    by 0x402E20: Image<Color>::readPPM(std::istream&) (Image.h:456)
==9968==    by 0x4040D3: main (main.cpp:85)
==9968== 
==9968== Invalid read of size 1
==9968==    at 0x404B92: operator*(float, Color const&) (Color.h:30)
==9968==    by 0x403532: Image<Color>::bilinearScale(unsigned short, unsigned short) const (Image.h:533)
==9968==    by 0x404109: main (main.cpp:86)
==9968==  Address 0x5dce721 is 1 bytes after a block of size 14,400 alloc'd
==9968==    at 0x4C2AFE7: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9968==    by 0x404CD7: Image<Color>::Image(unsigned short const&, unsigned short const&) (Image.h:173)
==9968==    by 0x402E20: Image<Color>::readPPM(std::istream&) (Image.h:456)
==9968==    by 0x4040D3: main (main.cpp:85)
```

This is my bilinearScale method

```
template <>
Image<Color>* Image<Color>::bilinearScale(ushort w, ushort h) const
{
    Image<Color> *gi = new Image<Color>(w, h);

    for(ushort _y = 0; _y <h ; _y++) { /* y' .. */
        for(ushort _x=0; _x < w; _x++) { /* .. et x' */

            float x =  (width * (float)_x) / w;
            float y = (height * (float)_y)/ h;
            ushort i = ushort(x);
            ushort j = ushort(y);
            float lambda = float(x-i);
            float mu = float(y -j);

            ushort iplus = ( i+1 >= w ? i : i+1);
            ushort jplus = ( j+1 >= h ? j : j+1);

            const Color &p1 = pixel(i, j);
            const Color &p2 = pixel(iplus, j);
            const Color &p3 = pixel(i, jplus);
            const Color &p4 = pixel(iplus, jplus);

            gi->pixel(_x, _y) = (1-lambda) * ( ((1-mu)* p1)+ mu*p3 ) + lambda * ( ((1-mu) * p2) + mu * p4);
        }
    }

    return gi;
}
```

Can somebody please tell me why I see invalid reads ?

The line 533 of bilinear is :

```
gi->pixel(_x, _y) = (1-lambda) * ( ((1-mu)* p1)+ mu*p3 ) + lambda * ( ((1-mu) * p2) + mu * p4);
```

This is my class Color :

```
typedef unsigned char ubyte;

class Color
{
public:

    ubyte red, green, blue;

    inline Color(ubyte r=0, ubyte g=0, ubyte b = 0) : red(r), green(g), blue(b)
    {}

    friend Color operator + ( float d, const Color& v )
    {
        return Color( ubyte(v.red+d), ubyte(v.green+d), ubyte(v.blue+d));
    }

    friend Color operator * ( float d, const Color& v )
    {
        return Color( ubyte(v.red*d), ubyte(v.green*d), ubyte(v.blue*d) );
    }

    Color operator + ( const Color& v );




};

Color Color::operator + ( const Color& c )
{
    return Color( red+c.red, green+c.green, blue+c.blue );
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of `Color::operator *(float, const Color&)`?

Comment: Break the offending line into separate statements to figure out which part is causing the problem.

Comment: @Pépito, it *looks* like the `pixel()` method sometimes returns a dangling reference to a `Color` instance (maybe a locally-allocated instance). I would double-check that `p1`...`p4` always contain valid data before performing the scaling computation.

Comment: I used the pixel() method before and it seems good. 

`template <typename T>
const T& Image<T>::pixel(ushort x, ushort y) const
{
    // check exception
    return array[width*y+x];
}

template <typename T>
T& Image<T>::pixel(ushort x, ushort y)
{
    // check exception
    
    return array[width*y+x];
}`

Comment: What are the dimensions of the original image and the re-scaled image?

Comment: have you used a debugger on this? check that width height etc have expected values.

Comment: The original is 80,60, the scaled will be 823,400. And it works. It just tell me this in valgrind

Comment: I would advise you to split the computation; instead of using one big expression use intermediary results, on different lines, and then valgrind will be able to pinpoint more accurately the exact part of the computation that fails.

Comment: If you add the "--vgdb-error=0" parameter to Valgrind command line, it will attach a debugger to the application when it finds an error. See http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver for details. This should allow to inspect i, j, iplus and jplus when the error happens. Also, does the error disappear if you compile without optimizations?

Comment: I'd check the values of i and j, especially towards the edge of the image.  Looking at how gcc and IEEE FP math is supposed to work, it all looks legit to me, but I feel slightly uncomfortable with the conversion from ushort to float back to ushort.  A 32 bit float should be good for ~8 digits of accuracy, which should be fine unless you have ridiculously large images.  Create two new images, one is 1 pixel wide with the original height, the other the original width but 1 pixel wide, and print out the values of i & j.